# Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Update 3: Setup Failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, failed-installation

I get an error like the following when I installing vs:

Setup Failed!
Install cannot continue because some reqiured components failed.

How can i fix that?

Log:

```
[1E70:0794][2014-09-07T01:25:09]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space before install:  SystemDrive C:\ 53684740096 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 53684740096 bytes
[2220:059C][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[2220:059C][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i361: Created a system restore point.
[2220:059C][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{71688083-99e8-4e10-9522-8e98a130c438}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1E70:1C44][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i000: MUX:  Cache Begin
[1E70:0794][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i000: MUX:  Vital packages to be installed: 24
[1E70:0794][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i000: MUX:  Total packages to be installed: 160
[1E70:1C44][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i338: Acquiring package: vs_preclean_vs, payload: vs_preclean_vs, copy from: F:\packages\VS_Clean\VS_PreClean_vs.exe
[2220:0B20][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i305: Verified acquired payload: vs_preclean_vs at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vs_preclean_vs, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\CEBEC741BC08D8490015A4BCD423266F7823BB72\packages\VS_Clean\VS_PreClean_vs.exe.
[1E70:1C44][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i000: MUX:  Source confirmed
[1E70:1C44][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i338: Acquiring package: Preparation_Uninstall_vs_ultimate, payload: Preparation_Uninstall_vs_ultimate, copy from: F:\packages\vs_ultimate\Preparation.exe
[1E70:0794][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vs_preclean_vs
[2220:059C][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i301: Applying execute package: vs_preclean_vs, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\CEBEC741BC08D8490015A4BCD423266F7823BB72\packages\VS_Clean\VS_PreClean_vs.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\CEBEC741BC08D8490015A4BCD423266F7823BB72\packages\VS_Clean\VS_PreClean_vs.exe" /ultimate /install /log C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_ultimate_20140907012458_157_vs_preclean_vs.log'
[1E70:1C44][2014-09-07T01:25:10]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed attempt to copy payload from: 'F:\packages\vs_ultimate\Preparation.exe' to: C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Local\Temp\{71688083-99e8-4e10-9522-8e98a130c438}\Preparation_Uninstall_vs_ultimate.
[1E70:1C44][2014-09-07T01:25:10]i000: MUX:  Acquire Failed.  Retry acquiring after sleeping for 3 seconds, Retry Count: 1 of 3
[1E70:0794][2014-09-07T01:25:11]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_preclean_vs MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[1E70:0794][2014-09-07T01:25:11]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1E70:0794][2014-09-07T01:25:11]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[1E70:0794][2014-09-07T01:25:11]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
```

[image: Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Update 3: Setup Faild]
[image: Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Update 3: Setup Faild]

Comment: Start setup as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild stab in the dark here but was the installer able to install a single file? It looks like a permissions issue off the bat, perhaps try to run it with admin privileges?